# How to determine probability of top 10 people from 25 people?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, probability

I have a group of 25 peoples I need only 10 people amongst them as a lucky winner so I want to all probable lists of these people what VBA code and which VBA function should I use?

I Want a lists of probable 10 people who will win the lucky draw

Comment: Where (Excel, Word) and how is your list stored? What kind of output do you expect?

Comment: the list is stored in excel

Comment: So what has the question to do with Word VBA?

Comment: I was looking for the VBA code for that

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without VBA.

List the names in column A. In column B you can use a Randbetween() function like

```
=RANDBETWEEN(1,25)
```

Turn the table into an Excel Table Object by using Insert > Table or Ctrl - T, while any cell of the list is selected.

Now you can use the filter option for **Top Ten** on the column drop-down in column B.

[image]

Comment: Hi Teylyn thanks for your response but I want to look for all lists at a single time but copy pasting every iteration time will increase rework hope you understand my query!